# How to print the current classpath with kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, classpath

I need to print the current classpath in a Kotlin program. What alternatives are?

My application is package in a jar file and I using Kotlin 1.3.61 and OpenJDK 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use:

```
(java.net.URLClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() as java.net.URLClassLoader).getURLs().forEach({println(it.getFile())})
```

Or

```
println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))
```

But there behave with differences, more details here: [What's the difference between System.getProperty("java.class.path") and getClassLoader.getURLs()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626396/whats-the-difference-between-system-getpropertyjava-class-path-and-getclass)