Py4JError. An error occurred while calling o229.save Delta Table
I'm trying to write delta table in to S3 bucket and getting this error.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o229.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormatWriter$Empty2Null

I'm using delta-spark:3.2.0, pyspark:3.5.1, Python:3.11, JDK 11, hadoop-aws:3.4.0 and delta-core_2.12:2.3.0

Did you add "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" and "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" when you create the Spark session?

Yes, These are my spark configurations,
conf = (
SparkConf()
.setAppName("MY_APP")
.set("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.3.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.4.0")
.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog","org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
.set("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", aws_access_key_id)
.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", aws_secret_access_key)
.setMaster("local[*]")
)

So when you say you use delta-spark==3.2.0, you mean you install the delta-spark python package but not the JAR? If this is true, you shouldn't use the delta-core JAR anymore. You should use io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0.

I can write delt tables in to the local storage using above configurations. But when I try to write to the S3 bucket it gives the above mentioned error. So I think it has something to do with the AWS SDK. I tried every AWS SDK version and still the same result.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76066363/unable-to-write-df-in-delta-format-on-hdfs does this help you?
